# How does an e-ticket work for a bus leaving Boston?

Tags: tickets, buses, boston

I bought e-tickets for my trip leaving from Boston. Can I go directly to the bus and show it to the driver or do I have to check in first at the ticket counter?

Comment: Which bus company is this?

Comment: @ZachLipton It's Boston so it doesn't matter. They all operate pretty much the same way in South Station. But based on the description it's most likely Greyhound; they're infamous for making passengers print out "e-tickets".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a printed e-ticket (or a QR code on your phone, or an old school paper folding ticket) for a bus leaving Boston South Station, you can skip the ticket counters and go directly to the departure gate. Turn right off the escalators and go through the middle passage between the ticket counters, for most gates. Note that multiple bus companies share the ticket counters and gates at South Station, so check the boards for your specific bus company, destination and departure time.

If you haven't got a printout of your ticket, the ticket counter (or Greyhound kiosk, for Greyhound buses) can print one out for you. Your bus company *might* charge for this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of e-ticket you purchased and which bus company you are travelling with.

Most bus companies "e-tickets" are tickets you can display on your phone.

- **Greyhound** sell three types of tickets online. Your confirmation should specific which type you have purchased. You can also convert your ticket to a different type on their website.

  - "E-Tickets" are tickets displayed on your phone. You need to
    [check-in online](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/road-rewards/e-ticket) using the link provided 2 hours before departure
    time or less, with this you can go straight to the gate or side of
    the bus.
  - "Print your ticket at home" you need to actually print the paper ticket on your own printer, with that you can go straight to the bus.
  - "Will call (pick up at the station)" go to the ticket from the counter or kiosk and pick up the paper ticket, then go to the bus.
- **Peter Pan**: just go straight to the side of the bus and show your phone.
- **Megabus**: go straight to the bus. You only need to tell the driver the unique block of four digits in your reservation code: (e.g. 6613 in 66-*6613*-071419-M1-2345-BOS-NYC).

Comment: It's about bloody time Greyhound came up with real "E"-tickets. Their previous iteration of "E-tickets" was the print-at-home ticket.

Comment: Indeed, it's only on select routes so far. Next iteration will hopefully not make people jump through the hoop of their whimsical online check-in process.

Comment: You'd think they would have figured it out by now. After all they own Boltbus and that's all QR codes on my app and no wasting paper...